# Manage InputBox method reference entry

Tags: vba

Exploring the VBA `Application.InputBox` method I've realized that catching user cancellation is tricky when type is reference, so return value is a range object.

As cancellation's return value is `False` I can't assign it to an object with `Set`, so I've created a UDF to return `Nothing` when user pressed cancel / Esc.

```
Function mjInputBox(prompt As String, title As String, default As Variant, dataType As Integer) As Variant

    If dataType = xlInputReference Then
        On Error GoTo InputCancelled
        Set mjInputBox = Application.InputBox(prompt:=prompt, title:=title, default:=default, Type:=dataType)
        On Error GoTo 0
    Else
        mjInputBox = Application.InputBox(prompt:=prompt, title:=title, default:=default, Type:=dataType)
    End If

    Exit Function

InputCancelled:
    Err.Clear
    Set mjInputBox = Nothing
End Function
```

(xlInputReference is a constant = 8)

Is it a good practice, or can I improve it?

- having a one line code instead of the UDF would be a big improvement
- According to [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839468.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396):

> For example, for an input box that can accept both text and numbers,
>   set Type to 1 + 2.

- Is it possible to combine input types including reference too? (note that I can assign return value of `inputBox` without `set` which will combine my reference to a cell value, which isn't acceptable).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The signature of your function doesn't match that of the function it's wrapping - that makes it potentially annoying to use, because one may or may not want to supply a `title` or a `default`; the only mandatory value in `Application.InputBox` is the `prompt` parameter - I'd expect an inputbox wrapper function to have an identical signature.

`xlInputReference` is confusing - it *looks* like a legit Excel object model enum member, but it's not. Avoid naming your own constants with `xl` prefixes, as these indicate Excel object model members, not custom user code.

I'd make an enum instead, and expose it to the client:

```
Public Enum InputType
    InputFormula = 0
    InputNumber = 1
    InputText = 2
    InputBoolean = 4
    InputCellRef = 8
    InputErrorValue = 16
    InputValueArray = 64
End Enum
```

That way the client code doens't need to remember or even try to figure out what values are legal and what they stand for - they even get IntelliSense for them!

---

One problem you're not dealing with, is that it's totally legal to supply a `3` and accept *both* text and numbers, or a `12` to accept both a boolean and a cell reference, or ...well any combination is a valid one.

Using the above enum, you could make a little utility function to verify whether an enum flag is set:

```
Private Function HasFlag(ByVal value As InputType, ByVal flag As InputType) As Boolean
    HasFlag = (value And flag) = flag
End Function
```

Now, combining flags for *number or text* makes sense, but if the client code is expecting a `Range`, and they allow any string too, it's their problem and they literally asked for an error to happen - the best you can do is tell them about the invalid `InputType` combo.

I'd use proper error handling for that. Perhaps raise a runtime error 5 ("Invalid procedure call or argument"), since it's the VBA equivalent of an `ArgumentException` (excuse my .net background).

The type-checking code is can definitely be more robust. Use the `VarType` function to determine if a `Variant` is a `Boolean`:

```
If VarType(result) = vbBoolean Then
```

You can also use the `IsObject` function to determine if your result is an object reference:

```
If IsObject(result) Then
```

You're implicitly passing parameters by reference, but they could (and should) be passed by value. I like that you're explicit about the `Variant` return type, but you should also be explicit about the `Public` accessibility of the function.

Combine all of the above, you get the below implementation:

```
Public Function InputBox(ByVal prompt As String, Optional ByVal title As String, Optional ByVal default As Variant, Optional ByVal dataType As InputType) As Variant

    On Error GoTo ErrHandler
    Dim canInputCellRef As Boolean
    canInputCellRef = HasFlag(dataType, InputCellRef)

    If canInputCellRef And dataType <> InputCellRef Then
        Err.Raise 5, Description:="Invalid input type combination."
    End If

    Dim result As Variant
    If canInputCellRef Then
        Set result = Application.InputBox(prompt, title, default, Type:=CInt(dataType))
    Else
        result = Application.InputBox(prompt, title, default, Type:=CInt(dataType))
    End If

    If VarType(result) = vbBoolean Then
        If Not CBool(result) Then
            'inputbox was cancelled
            If canInputCellRef Then
                Set InputBox = Nothing
            End If
            Exit Function
        End If
    End If

    If IsObject(result) Then
        Set InputBox = result
    Else
        InputBox = result
    End If

CleanExit:
    Exit Function

ErrHandler:
    If Err.Number = 5 Then
        MsgBox Err.Description, vbExclamation, "InputBox"
        'note: client code will error if the returned value is set at call site
        Resume CleanExit
    Else
        result = False
        Resume Next
    End If
End Function
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! It really helped a lot to improve the function.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure where you got `xlInputReference` from, or `16`. According to the MSDN page you linked, the correct type for a reference input is `8`.

I'm not sure I like your approach. You only need this for range inputs. Personally, I would handle this (prompting for range inputs) by asking for a cell reference (as text) then converting that text into a range object separately (with appropriate error handling).

But, to take your current approach:

---

As it stands, I've got very little that I can see improvements for.

You shouldn't use `Integer`. It is completely deprecated. Use `Long` instead.

Your method name isn't great and breaks convention (that Metohd names use `PascalCase`). I would use something like `HandleInputBox`.

Since yes, you can have compound return types but obviously, trying to return some combination of object + text + number is going to fail, you probably want to check for it:

```
If dataType Mod 16 >= 8 Then
    If dataType <> 8 Then
    '/ Compound of 8 with other values
        '/ Error handling
    Else
        On Error GoTo InputCancelled
        Set mjInputBox = Application.InputBox(prompt:=prompt, Title:=Title, Default:=Default, Type:=dataType)
        On Error GoTo 0
    End If
Else
    mjInputBox = Application.InputBox(prompt:=prompt, Title:=Title, Default:=Default, Type:=dataType)
End If
```

You should probably implement all the other optional arguments for `Application.InputBox()` as well since you only have to pass them through.

Other than that, I have nothing to critique. The code is good.

Comment: [Rubberduck](http://www.rubberduckvba.com) code inspections would have revealed the implicit access modifier and `ByRef` parameters ;-)

Comment: @Mat'sMug Sure, if RD didn't crash my computer every time I reinstall it.

Comment: "asking for a cell reference (as text)" - I know it would be easier to manage, the problem with that is it's more difficult to manage for the users.